# Named router-outlet with async child routers

Tags: angular, router, router-outlet

I working in project with Angular 6.1.0.

I need load in a region (named router outlet) in the "App component" another component configured with async router.

While in the changelog of version 6.1.0 it says:

> router: fix lazy loading of aux routes (# 23459) (5731d07), closes #
>   10981

In my project, this not working:

Root router configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "products", component: ProductListComponent },
  { path: "product/:id", component: ProductDetailComponent },
  {
    path: "",
    component: SidebarComponent,
    outlet: "sidebar"
  },
  {
    path: "products",
    component: ProductListSidebarComponent,
    outlet: "sidebar"
  },
  {
    path: "tests",
    loadChildren: "app/test-async/test.async.module#TestAsyncModule"
  }
];

export const routingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Test Async Module (Router Configuration)

```
const TEST_ROUTER: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: TAsyncComponent,
        outlet: 'sidebar'
    }
];

export const routes = RouterModule.forChild(TEST_ROUTER);
```

App Component (Template)

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
        Welcome to {{ title }}!
    </h1>
    <h2>
        Read <a href="https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router/">Angular router tutorial</a> and 
        <a href="https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-tutorial/">Angular 6 tutorial</a>
    </h2>

    <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: ['products'],sidebar: ['products'] } }]">
        Products
    </a>

    <br>
    <br>

    <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: ['products'],sidebar: ['tests'] } }]">
        Tests
    </a>

</div>

<div>
    <div style="float:right">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">    
        <router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

When test link is clicked, this error is shown in the console.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tests'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tests'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.umd.js:1455)
    ...
```

If the route is configured directly, with no asynchronous load, the link behaves in the correct way.

Here I leave a sandbox with the project, so you can see the error.

[image: Edit angular-45-router-demo]

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: 8/8/2018**

If I change the root configuration for :

```
{
   path: "tests",
   loadChildren: "app/test-async/test.async.module#TestAsyncModule" 
   outlet: 'sidebar'
}
```

and in the module routing i change for:

```
{
  path: '',
  component: TAsyncComponent,
}
```

the routing work!!

BUT .... I am forcing all the routes defined in the asynchronously loaded module to be rendered in a certain region and not that the route can decide the region defined in the parent. (import module)

Perhaps it is a problem of concept, and the routes are hierarchical and accessible downwards and do not allow access to routes defined at a higher level in the hierarchy.

Can someone clarify this?
Concept problem? Or, is it something that is missing in the Angular routing?